# c++ Calling functions across multiple .cpp files?

Tags: c++, function, call, header-files

I have 3 files:
- main.cpp
- other.cpp
- other.h

I am trying to call a function that was declared in other.h, from main.cpp, with the code being written in other.cpp

My code:

main.cpp:

```
//#Allmyincludes
#include "other.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char *file = argv[1];
    read(file);
    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp:

```
//#Allmyincludes
#include "other.h"

void read(const char *file)
{
    //code
}
```

other.h:

```
void read(const char *file);
```

The error I get is:

`main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 'read(char const*)'`

Within `read()`, I am using `main::variableName` to access variables from within main (no errors), however I just can't get the function call to work.
If I try to do `other::read(file);` that also doesn't work because `::` is for functions and not files. It gives me the error: `'other' has not been declared.`

Any explanation as to why my header file/call isn't working is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your compilation command. If using GCC (i.e. `g++`) notice that order of program arguments to the compiler matters a big lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many causes of undefined reference errors. In your case, from what you've described, the likeliest is that you haven't compiled other.cpp

You need to add other.cpp to your project/makefile/command line.

For more detailed help you probably need to explain how you are building your program. There is nothing actually wrong with the code, it's the way you build your program that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you.
I only had g++ main.cpp -Wall -o main

Answer (score 0):

try

> gcc -Wall main.cpp other.cpp -o mymain